# `DebugActiveProcessStop' undeclared (first use this function)

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

The question is same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643182/win32-api-functions-not-found) one, however, the solution doesn't work for me.

According to the [DebugActiveProcessStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679296(v=vs.85).aspx) function documentation, the minimum supported client is Windows XP. I am using Windows 7.

```
// #ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
// #undef _WIN32_WINNT
// #endif

#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010000
// #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class CppDBG
{
    ...
    public:
        BOOL detach (void);
        ...
};

...

BOOL CppDBG :: detach (void)
{
    if (DebugActiveProcessStop(pid)) {
        cout << "[+] Finished debugging. Exiting...";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "[-] Error" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CppDBG dbg;
    ...
    dbg.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I am using Windows 7` - and so what ? absolute no matter on which system you compile your code. important only which *sdk* version you use (and are use at all). if you use *sdk* - simply search where `DebugActiveProcessStop` is declared, are it in conditional block (*#if*) and you conform this conditions

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your IDE has an old version of the Windows API installed.

The error you get is a compiler error telling you that the compiler does not know what `DebugActiveProcessStop` is. For the compiler this can be anything (e.g. variable, constant, ...). This error has nothing to do with the version of Windows your system is running with.

To fix this try downloading the [Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) from Microsoft and tell your compiler to use it (change include directories, library paths, ...). This heavily depends on the IDE you are using. But the internet should provide enough help.

Comment: If your compiler is MinGW, it's likely you are using an ancient MinGW that doesn't have any API that was introduced after Windows 2000. Get MinGW-w64 instead; that is constantly being updated.